# Simple javascript functions seem to break on jQuery Datatables after paging

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm having an interesting problem that I hope there's an easy solution to. I'm using jQuery Datatables plugin (datatables.net) and I have the paging set to full numbers. In my rows, I have a delete button that when clicked performs a jQuery function. The function simply calls an external source to handle the delete in the database, and uses .remove() to remove the row from the UI.

This works flawlessly until I use paging. If I have more than 10 records, and click to the next page, it no longer works. Here's some code:

```
jQuery('.deleterecord').click(function(){
    var conf = confirm('Continue delete?');
        if(conf)
            jQuery(this).parents('tr').fadeOut(function(){
            jQuery(this).remove();
            jQuery.jGrowl("Record has been removed!");
        });

    return false;
 });
```

So I have a link in the row:

```
<a class="deleterecord">Delete</a>
```

This calls the click function. So if I click to the next page through paging on the table, the only way I can get this function to work again is if I refresh the page with cookies enabled to remember the page.

Any ideas I hope??? :(

Comment: use the datatables API to both add the handler and remove the row. Otherwise it will not be removed from the data store within plugin and will get shown again when you sort or change pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Datatables has a built-in function to removes rows, [fnDeleteRow (documentation-link)](http://datatables.net/ref#fnDeleteRow). This would handle the correct state of the pagination and, even more important, the actual data within the plugin itself.

I created a [little example on jsBin](http://jsbin.com/aliqar/1/edit) to show you.

I used the markup from one of the examples, so it may look a little messy.

So basically, you bind a click-handler on a row and delegate the event on a td, you could do the same with your button, just change the `.center` in the handler to `.deleterecord` and prevent the default event.

The only difference would be the `this`-variable used when calling `fnGetPosition` to get the actual id of the row, which you need for the deleteRow-Function. You would probably need to use something like `$(this).parent()[0]` instead to pass a `td` - element rather than your button.

This is the code of the handler and the init-call for the datatables-plugin for the sake of completeness:

```
  $('#example tbody tr').on('click', '.center', function () {
    var aPos = oTable.fnGetPosition(this);
    oTable.fnDeleteRow(aPos[0]);
  });

  // Init DataTables
  oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers"
  });
```

Inside the handler, you'd need to set off an ajax - call to the database to delete the correct row and execute this code-snippet in the callback, if the server returns a positive result.

Comment: First, thank you so much for taking so much time to help a stranger! I was able to replace my method with the proper one from your example/datatables.net. I can't believe I missed this. My problem of paging still exists though... and I'm not sure what's wrong. Everything is working perfectly until I page. If I goto the next page in the table and try the delete function, it does not work.

Comment: The only difference in my situation is utilizing the button instead of the clicking on the row with specified class. I used $(this).parent... etc. which, works until paging. :(

Comment: I have a theory... Perhaps something isn't working properly with .on which is the new .live? So the event handler is only grabbing the first result set, which is causing the function to not be triggered after paging?

Comment: I tried this [link](http://www.datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/plugin_api.html) and was able to re-create with button click returning the number of/all the tr notes... but still doesn't work when paging. Going insane!!!

Comment: For some reason, the delete row works when using .on, but the paging issue still has problems. If I change to .live, the paging works fine, but the row doesn't delete! Insane.

Comment: @user1447679 just curious, what jQuery-version are you using?

Comment: or, I guess I could help you out better if you could provide a live example to look at, this seems like an odd issue

Comment: 1.7.2 on the jquery. What a nightmare. I was able to fix this with your help so definitely marking your answer correct. To be honest I went back and forth so much I'm not sure where I went wrong the first round... but I have that fantastic feeling of something finally working as it should. I even stress tested it and tried everything I could do to break it, and it survived!!! Thank you so much.