# Can't use other jQuery function after DataTable paging

Tags: jquery, ajax, datatables

Thanks to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25775478/jquery-addclass-removeclass-after-ajax-success) I have successfully added in an ajax update along with some class swapping on my datatable data.  However, once I jump to the next page the ajax function doesn't fire and it doesn't return any errors.  It seems like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14947443/simple-javascript-functions-seem-to-break-on-jquery-datatables-after-paging) has the same problem though it so happens that there was a built-in datatables function to solve that one which I doubt there is in my case.

HTML:

```
<table id="datatable" class="display dataTable" role="grid">
  <tbody>
    <tr class="odd" role="row">
      <td class="formcell"><input id="actionitem" class="box" type="checkbox" value="1234" name="actionitem[]"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="even" role="row">
      <td class="formcell"><input id="actionitem" class="box" type="checkbox" value="5678" name="actionitem[]"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#datatable").dataTable( {
    bFilter: false
  });
  $(".box").change(function() {
    var id=$(this).val();
    var dataString = "id=" + id + "&crudtype=myapp";
    var clickedObj = $(this).parent().parent();
    $.ajax( {
        type: "POST",
        url: "/myphppage",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function() {
          var oldClass = clickedObj.attr("class");
          clickedObj.fadeTo(1, 1.0, function(){
          clickedObj.removeClass(oldClass).addClass("updated");
          clickedObj.fadeTo(3000, 1.0, function(){
            clickedObj.removeClass("updated").addClass(oldClass);
          });
        });
      } 
    });
  });
});
```

Again, on the first page it all works like a champ.  I assume the problem is that the ajax function is setup when the DOM is setup and that it doesn't react to the changes caused by datatable paging but I don't know enough about jQuery to know if that's right or how to fix it.  Thanks to anyone who can help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). When the datatables plugin switches pages, the current `.box` elements are removed and the new ones are put into the table. With event delegation, you can bind the event to the table, so that the new `.box`'s should also fire the event.

Change

```
$(".box").change(function() {
```

To

```
$("#datatable").on("change", ".box", function() {
```

Sidenote: the `this` inside the function still refers to the `.box` element.

Comment: Brilliant -- wish I could buy you a beer or other cocktail of your choice.  Thanks a bunch!